# SecuGen SDK integration in Android Apps

Tags: java, android, biometrics

I have embedded secugen android sdk in my apps but I am facing an issue when fingerprint image sending to the server and template is not forming properly

Comment: So what was your question again? Any code to show us?

Comment: post you code to help in debugging

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is construction of images then this might help:
Check whether you are able to construct the image or not. Because Scugen uses 1D byte array to capture image data So if you try to construct image from 1D array It will give distorted image. So using image width you can convert 1D byte array into 2D array and then you can construct image.